# Invert a dictionary of multiple sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

Suppose I have a dict of sets:

```
DictofSets={
    'Key1':set(['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key2':set(['B', 'C', 'G']),
    'Key3':set(['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key4':set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key5':set(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'])}
```

Now suppose I want to find the keys of set elements in the sets that occur in more than one set.

The best I could do is something along the lines of:

```
from collections import Counter

# first get counts of elements in excess of 1:
c=Counter()
for s in DictofSets.values():
    c+=Counter(s)

# dict of lists for the keys if the set item occurs more than once
inverted={k:[] for k, v in c.items() if v>1} 
for k in sorted(DictofSets):
    for e in DictofSets[k]:
        if e in inverted:
            inverted[e].append(k)
```

It produces what I want:

```
>>> inverted
{'A': ['Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5'], 
 'C': ['Key2', 'Key4'], 
 'B': ['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5'], 
 'D': ['Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4'], 
 'F': ['Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5']}
```

But it seems kinda clumsy. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: There is already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039730/return-a-dictionary-with-keys-for-a-given-dictionarys-values-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Probs a better way to create `inverted`: `inverted = {k: [] for k,v in Counter(chain(*DictofSets.values())).items() if v > 1}`. As for the final loop, I can't think of another way atm but I don't find too clumsy tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the OP approach. It could be expressed with more brevity but that doesn't make this any better:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> c = Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(DictofSets.values()))
>>> {l: {k for k, s in DictofSets.items() if l in s} for l, n in c.items() if n > 1}
{'A': {'Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5'},
 'B': {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5'},
 'C': {'Key2', 'Key4'},
 'D': {'Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4'},
 'F': {'Key1', 'Key3', 'Key4', 'Key5'}}
```

Comment: Should instead use `[k for k, s in sorted(DictofSets.items()) if l in s]` to keep the ordering (as it seems is required) and, I personally would use `chain.from_iterable` or `chain` to get a speed bump with the Counter initialization.

Comment: If `sorted` is needed, which the OP shows, then doing it in a loop like the OP is probably better. Agree with `chain`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a job for defaultdict

```
>>> DictofSets={
    'Key1':set(['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key2':set(['B', 'C', 'G']),
    'Key3':set(['A', 'B', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key4':set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']),
    'Key5':set(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'])}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> SetsofDicts = defaultdict(set)
>>> for key, values in DictofSets.items():
        for x in values:
            SetsofDicts[x].add(key)


>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(SetsofDicts)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
            {'A': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key4'},
             'B': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key2', 'Key4'},
             'C': {'Key4', 'Key2'},
             'D': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key4'},
             'E': {'Key5'},
             'F': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key4'},
             'G': {'Key2'}})
>>>
```

once you get that, removing the undesired entries is easy, and there is plenty of ways of doing it, like for example

```
>>> for toremove in [ k for k,v in SetsofDicts.items() if len(v)<=1 ]:
        del SetsofDicts[toremove]


>>> pprint(SetsofDicts)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
            {'A': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key4'},
             'B': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key2', 'Key4'},
             'C': {'Key4', 'Key2'},
             'D': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key4'},
             'F': {'Key3', 'Key1', 'Key5', 'Key4'}})
>>>
```

Comment: Entries with a single match shouldn't be included according to OPs output.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard there is a plethora of ways to remove the undesired entries, I included one

Comment: Sure, don't know if this could be considered "easier" than OPs solution, though, but that's subjective either way.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard well, by using sets I don't need to worry about checking if I already use a certain key, and everything can be done in just one dictionary, and not 2 as the OP is doing

Comment: Right but by using sets you lose the ordering (which OP seems to want judging by the `sorted(DictofSets)`). Either way, OP actually has the final word, I'm simply observing (I don't really find his solution so "clumsy" :P)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard right, that sorted call bugged me, I did not realized that alongside using list it preserve the order... in that case using list and check for membership accomplished the same

Comment: The `sorted` call is so the keys come out in order. The actual case is a dict of dates, so it is better if they are in ascending order. Thanks for noticing the `sorted` call -- it did have a purpose.